# Sort by array length mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to sort a search by the size of an array, I tried to do the following in mongodb and it worked:

```
db.getCollection('tweet').aggregate({ $unwind:'$complaints'}, 
                 { $group : {_id:'$_id', count:{$sum:1}}}, 
                 { $sort :{ count: 1}})
```

this return:

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fade9754b0cac60df630ab2"),
    "count" : 2.0
}
```

in Go try doing this

```
update := bson.M{
    "$group": bson.M{
        "count": bson.M{"$sum": 1},
    },
}




conditions:= make([]bson.M, 0)
conditions= append(conditions, bson.M{"$unwind": "$complaints"})
conditions= append(conditions, bson.M{"$sort": bson.M{"count": -1}})
conditions= append(conditions, update)
conditions= append(conditions, bson.M{"$skip": skip})
conditions= append(conditions, bson.M{"$limit": 20})

cursor, err := col.Aggregate(ctx, conditions)
var result []models.complaintsCount
err = cursor.All(ctx, &result)
if err != nil {
    return result, false
```

the struct models.complaintsCount:

```
type complaintsCount struct {
    ID    primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id" json:"_id,omitempty"`
    Count int                `bson:"count" json:"count"`
}
```

but return error, Any way to do it?

Comment: Your group statement is missing the _id, and sort should be after the group